# setuptools very simple (one source file module) configuration

Tags: python, configuration, pip, setuptools, devpi

I want to use `setuptools` to create a package consisting of two files: `foo.py` (script) and `foo.conf`.

Then I want to publish the package on my `devpi-server` and then install the package using `pip`.

Suppose I that initially I have my current working directory clean

```
$ ls -l
total 0
```

Then I issue `pip install` (or `download`?) command

```
$ pip install -i http://mydevpi.server foo
```

And get a dir with my two files created

```
$ tree
.
|
foo
|
|\_ foo.py
|
 \_ foo.conf
```

So questions are:

- what `setuptools` configuration should I use?
- what exact `pip` command should I use to install the package the way I want? Will `pip install -i http://mydevpi.server --target=.` do the trick?

Comment: You can install in local directory and use `setuptools` to write a `setup.py`

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Will `pip install -i http://mydevpi.server --target=.` do the trick?

Comment: Maybe you can create a wheel file  from the source, see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/ and install using `pip install the_wheel_file_path`

Answer (score 0):

First write somethings as `setup.py` in *foo* directory like:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='foo_pip',
    version='1',
    packages=[''],
    url='1',
    license='1',
    author='1',
    author_email='1',
    description='1'
)
```

(You can use `distutils` or `setuptools`)

Then `python setup.py bdist_wheel -d TARGET` and there will be a `whl` file in `target` directory, copy the path.

You can now install using `pip install the_wheel_file_path  --prefix="the_path_to_install"`

Something like this

```
Processing .../TARGET/foo_pip-1-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: foo-pip
Successfully installed foo-pip-1
```

Then use it by `import foo`

Comment: What would be the `pip install` command to install the package that way but not from local path, but from `pypi`?

Comment: @konstunn You should first upload the package to pypi see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi

Comment: The solution you have provided does not solve my problem. Maybe I want to use things the wrong way, but I want to install the package in custom working directory. You have suggested creating a wheel in custom working directory, but after `pip install` this wheel will be installed in usual manner.

Comment: @konstunn sorry about  the mistake, but you can use `--prefix"` to specify the install directory